# How to add an apple delegate to a list of fruit delegates?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, covariance, contravariance

I have a sample program with a base `Fruit` class and a derived `Apple` class.

```
class Testy
{
    public delegate void FruitDelegate<T>(T o) where T : Fruit;

    private List<FruitDelegate<Fruit>> fruits = new List<FruitDelegate<Fruit>>();

    public void Test()
    {
        FruitDelegate<Apple> f = new FruitDelegate<Apple>(EatFruit);

        fruits.Add(f); // Error on this line
    }

    public void EatFruit(Fruit apple) { }
}
```

I want to have a list of fruit delegates and be able to add delegates of more derived fruit to the list. I believe this has something to do with covariance or contravariance but I cannot seem to figure it out.

The error message is (without namespaces):

```
The best overloaded method match for 'List<FruitDelegate<Fruit>>.Add(FruitDelegate<Fruit>)' has some invalid arguments`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *FruitDelegate<Fruit>* is a delegate that accepts any fruit. For example, the following is valid:

```
FruitDelegate<Fruit> f = new FruitDelegate<Fruit>(EatFruit);
f(new Apple());
f(new Banana());
```

You can make the type parameter *T* of *FruitDelegate<T>* [contravariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx):

```
public delegate void FruitDelegate<in T>(T o) where T : Fruit;
```

which allows you to assign a *FruitDelegate<Fruit>* instance to a *FruitDelegate<Apple>* variable:

```
FruitDelegate<Apple> f = new FruitDelegate<Fruit>(EatFruit);
f(new Apple());
```

This is valid, because the delegate refers to a method that (among other fruits) accepts apples.

However, you cannot assign a *FruitDelegate<Apple>* instance to a *FruitDelegate<Fruit>* variable:

```
FruitDelegate<Fruit> f = new FruitDelegate<Apple>(EatApple); // invalid
f(new Apple());
f(new Banana());
```

This is invalid, because the delegate should accept any fruit, but would refer to a method that accepts no fruit other than apples.

Conclusion: you cannot add a *FruitDelegate<Apple>* instance to a *List<FruitDelegate<Fruit>>*, because a *FruitDelegate<Apple>* is not a  *FruitDelegate<Fruit>*.